Inconsistency on using comments to "add more information"
If you open the comment box, the grayed-out tooltip text says

Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information [emphasis mine]

However, the faq says

They are not for:

Providing additional information that may be needed to formulate an answer; instead, important information from the original author should be edited into the question


I suggest to resolve this inconsistency.

Site dependent. Worldbuilding comment suggestion box states: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.". Presumably raise on that site's meta - or do you mean here?

@W.O. Thanks, I did not notice that the content of the box was site-dependent. You are right, the tooltip is different here.

@JohnOmielan I don't think that suggestion resolves any ambiguity. You could "ask either for", or, better yet, "either ask for clarification or ask for more information", if that's the intended meaning.

No, the tooltip is actually the same here on Meta. I'd suggest to remove the "add" from the comment tooltip.

Ah, I see now, the reason I saw a different tooltip on this question is that I am the asker. Apparently askers get a different tooltip. Very unexpected difference, but it makes sense.

Generally speaking, the FAQ is not official and is maintained and edited by ordinary users, while site UI (e.g. tooltips) is maintained by SE staff. So it's natural that it's not consistent, but I do agree it should be addressed, one way or another. (And if you want full consistency, there is the Help Center which is maintained by SE itself.)

This isn’t an inconsistency; it’s just that the comment box text isn’t phrased very well.
What it’s supposed to mean is:

Use comments to ask for clarification or [to ask for OP to] add more information [to the post (via edits)].


I’d support rewording this comment box text to something clearer, such as:

Use comments to ask for clarification or more information to be edited into the post.


I think the idea of comments being transitory is helpful here. So let's say the question revolves around something I have subject matter expertise in. I have information that could lead to an answer say "could you try turning it off and on again?" - but I'm not certain that's the answer, or I've some information on the system that's not in the question. That should be a comment, in the expectation that it gets rolled into a proper post as things go on.
Let's say you see a user running a wrong command as part of their troubleshooting process - suggesting the 'correct' command wouldn't be an answer - but is useful information. The expectation is that the user tries the command suggested in the comments, then edits their question with the output, rather than replying to the comment in the comments. Alternatively, another user can edit it in, and flag the comment as no longer needed. In other cases I might know something I think the OP might find useful but I'm unsure if it fits their intent. All these are temporary and helpful in finding the answer eventually.
One doesn't expect those comments to stay - and the question should be self-contained as much as possible. The goal here is to keep the comments neat.

You are absolutely right, but I wonder how much of an answer this is to the question at hand. Maybe this should have been a comment :)

I'd say if it was a comment, maybe it should be an answer. Or perhaps its the constant tug between a tech centric community where people expect clean answers, and social software, which invariably is messy.  If someone asks me for clarification, it eventually belongs in my post. As perhaps this comment should :D

Regarding the FAQ, the latest edit (revision 77) to that wiki changed some of the wording/phrasing in your second quote.
It used to read:

They [comments] are not for:

The question author to provide additional information that may be needed to formulate an answer.  Important information from the original author should be edited into the question instead


But it was edited to:

They [comments] are not for:

Providing additional information that may be needed to formulate an answer; instead, important information from the original author should be edited into the question


I don’t know why “The question author” was removed from the start, but I think it changes the meaning.  And I suggest rolling this edit back.
As Journeyman Geek’s answer points out (if I understand it rightly), comments from other users can and should be used for adding information.  This is not clear in revision 77.

Really, it's question and answer authors who shouldn't be providing essential information in comments.

I deleted the text because I felt it was too wordy compared to the bold text at the beginning of other bullets. I didn't feel like I was making a significant change since the rest of the bullet still mentions the question author. I also didn't get the same impression from their answer - the examples they provided (such as asking if a given command works) are also asking for information, not merely adding information, and they do mention that users can edit information into others' questions.

In general, the ideal number of comments approaches zero. Its a non ideal world ;D
